# AngularJS - Cannot get $q.reject and to work

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, promise, angular-promise

Take a look at my code sample:

I've stripped it down to (what I believe are) the bare essentials, and I'm setting getting an error `deferred.reject is not a function`

```
angular
    .module('myApp')
    .service('myService', MyService);

MyService.$inject = ['$http', '$q'];

function MyService($http, $q) {
    var self = this;

    self.getResult = getResult;

    function getResult(id) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        deferred = $http.get('my/api/method', { params: { id: id } })
            .then(getResultCompleted)
            .catch(getResultFailed);

        function getResultCompleted(response) {
            if (response.data.ID > 0) {
                deferred.resolve(response.data);
            } else {
                deferred.reject(response);
            }
        }

        function getResultFailed(response) {
            deferred.reject(response);
        }

        return deferred.promise;
    }
}
```

**Note**: I know I can get this to work by simply returning the result of the $http call, however for the purposes of understanding these promise objects, I want to see if I can get this working by declaring and returning `deferred` as shown above

Thanks!

Comment: `$http.get()` returns promise, but not deferred

Comment: @Vadim: I don't understand. Can you please elbourate?

Comment: I'm referring `deferred = $http.get()` string. It is incorrect, because `$http.get()` returns not the deferred object, but it's promise. So, you can just return the `$http.get`

Answer (score 3):

You are creating custom promise and returning it from your method, but mean while dealing with it you are overriding `deferred`(custom promise object) with `$http.get`, which also returns promise which has `.then` & `.catch` methods(Which doesn't have `resolve` & `reject` method). Because of that assignment, you can't have access to `.resolve` and `.reject` from `deferred` object.

```
deferred = $http.get('my/api/method', { params: { id: id } })
```

should be only

```
$http.get('my/api/method', { params: { id: id } })
```

Comment: Thanks @PankajParkar. I'm still a bit unclear here. If it's being assigned the value of $http.get's return result, wouldn't this essentially mean it takes on the value?

Comment: @Ricky No..Thats not how promise works.. Promise means you said that, I have something to return & I'll have it after some time..That's why you created `var deferred = $q.defer();` and when you received a response you make it `resolve` with data & `reject` with the same data.. If you do `deferred = $http.get('my/api/method', { params: { id: id } })` in between it..It will flush out whole object the traditional `$http.get` promise object will introduce in it..

Answer (score 1):

Since `$http.get()` returns promise and success callback supports chaining API, you can define new deferred object inside of a callback and return it from there:

```
angular
    .module('myApp')
    .service('myService', MyService);

MyService.$inject = ['$http', '$q'];

function MyService($http, $q) {
    var self = this;

    self.getResult = getResult;

    function getResultCompleted(response) { // Tip: Define callback outside of getResult in order to avoid creating new instance of it each time getResult is called
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        if (response.data.ID > 0) {
            deferred.resolve(response.data);
        } else {
            deferred.reject(response);
        }
        return deferred.promise;
    }

    function getResult(id) {
        return $http.get('my/api/method', { params: { id: id } })
            .then(getResultCompleted);
    }
}
```

Note, that there is no error callback any more (just because it is redundant in this case).

In case request failed, the original rejected promise from `$http.get()` will be returned, otherwise a brand new promise from success callback will be used for follow-up `.then()` calls.

Comment: Thanks @Vadim. Where would `deferred` bet declared? I do not see it in your code (although perhaps I missed it)

Comment: @Vadim I don't understand why you are playing with `deferred` object as you returned `$http.get` promise already

Comment: @PankajParkar Once promise is resolved, you can't reject it any longer. Since the original promise from `$http` was already resolved and you need to reject it under certain condition, you need to create new promise and for this you need new deferred.

Comment: @Vadim are you sure? its not like you are thinking because of your returned promise like `return $http.get('my/api/method', { params: { id: id } })` line, it should be `return deferred.promise` to make it working

Comment: @PankajParkar Take a look at this plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/ALbjvYlskBqMAgHH6bu3?p=preview. To understand how it works you can play with URL of `$http.get()`

Comment: @Vadim oh man..I'm sorry I didn't saw you 2nd & 3rd edit..which returned `return deferred.promise;` from the function.. +1 for yours.